# Change possition on Registration form of extra fiels added to users

Tags: user, form, registration

I have added an extra field for membership number to Users but I cannot see how to specify where the field is displayed on the registration form. It comes as a separate section at the end after the Capcha box.
Is there a way I can have it displayed with the rest as the first item on the form?